# Is there any package similar to verbatim but with support for icons?

Tags: verbatim, framed

I am looking for a package that provides verbatim environments but also supports different background color, frame style and icons (tips, error, warning etc.) shown on the upper-left corner.

Comment: Take a look at the `listings` package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings

Comment: Thanks. I tried that one, it does supports different background color and different frame style. But it seems that it doesn't support the icon. I am looking for something like this http://postimage.org/image/d2ph3mzpt/

Comment: You can escape from a listing to LaTeX using a self-specified Character (so it does not interfere with your usual code) and include (by doing that) any image inside or besides the Code. I'll try something like that in the evening.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package currently does not support the use of icons, and frame styles are limited. However, it is possible to combine the provided `SaveVerbatim` environment with the `\fcolorbox` command (provided by the [`xcolor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package) to get some interesting results.

### Declarations

The strategy is to first save parsed data (text) to a storage bin using the `SaveVerbatim` environment. Next the `\printmacro` and `\printmacroi` commands use the parsed data saved to the *last* storage bin. The icons are included using `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
   \definecolor{LightGray}{RGB}{193,193,193}
   \definecolor{LightYellow}{RGB}{253,247,172}

%%%%% \printmacro

\newcommand{\printmacro}[1][mc]{% mc = label of storange bin
%
{\setlength{\fboxrule}{3.0\fboxrule}% thickness of frame
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5\fboxsep}% separation between text and frame
%
\noindent%
\fcolorbox{LightGray}{LightYellow}{% frame and background color
%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth - 2.0\fboxrule - 2.0\fboxsep}
\protect\UseVerbatim[fontsize=\footnotesize]{#1} % font size of text in verbatim
\end{minipage}}%
}%
}

%%%% \printmacroi

% \macroicon is used by \printmacroi to print the icon and some horizontal space
\newcommand{\macroicon}{%
\hspace{1em}%
\parbox[c]{0.75cm}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,width=0.75cm]{light-bulb-icon}}%
\hspace{1em}%
}

% \newmacroicon provides a quicker way to renew \macroicon mid-document
\newcommand{\newmacroicon}[3][1em]{%
\renewcommand{\macroicon}{%
\hspace{#1}%
\parbox[c]{#2}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,width=#2]{#3}}%
\hspace{#1}%
}}

\newlength\macroiconwidth

\newcommand{\printmacroi}[1][mc]{%
%
{\setlength{\fboxrule}{3.0\fboxrule}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5\fboxsep}%
%
\noindent%
\fcolorbox{LightGray}{LightYellow}{%
%
\macroicon%
\settowidth{\macroiconwidth}{\macroicon}%
%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth - \macroiconwidth - 2.0\fboxrule - 2.0\fboxsep}
\protect\UseVerbatim[fontsize=\footnotesize]{#1}
\end{minipage}}%
}%
}
```

### Usage

Next I show how to use `\printmacro`, `\printmacroi` and `\newmacroicon` mid-document:

```
\begin{document}

Here's the first example with no icon:

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{mc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\printmacro

\noindent
The second and third examples contain icons. The \verb+\newmacroicon+ command
is used midway to change the type of icon used:

\begin{SaveVerbatim}[commandchars=\|\(\)]{mc}
\(|color(OliveGreen)DeclareMicrotypeSet){basictext}
   { encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5},
     family = {rm*,sf*},
     series = {md*},
     size = {normalsize,footnotesize,small}
   }
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\printmacroi

Now a different icon will be used:

\newmacroicon{0.75cm}{warning-icon}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{mc}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basictext}
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\printmacroi

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Tips

- You must always place `\printmacro` (no icon) or `\printmacroi` on the line after `\end{SaveVerbatim}`.
- To change the default font size of text in verbatim, go to the line `\protect\UseVerbatim[fontsize=\footnotesize]{#1}` and use `\small`, or `\normalsize`, etc. instead of `\footnotesize`.
- The thickness of the frame  and separation between text and frame are set by `\fboxrule`, and `\fboxsep`, respectively. You can either use explicit values, for example `\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5cm}`, or use multiples of the default dimensions, e.g., `\setlength{\fboxrule}{5.0\fboxrule}` gives 5 times the default frame thickness.
- When declaring the command `\macroicon` in the preamble(!), you must ensure the image file you use (e.g., `light-bulb.png`} is either in the same directory as your main document, or in a visible path.
- You can change the icon mid-document with the `\newmacroicon` command. For example, `\newmacroicon[0.5cm]{2cm}{exclamation-mark}` sets the horizontal space before and after the icon to 0.5cm, sets the width of the icon to 2cm, and loads a new icon (the image file `exclamation-mark`). Alternatively, you can use `\newmacroicon{2cm}{exclamation-mark}` (this way you don't need to specify the horizontal space).
- If you just want to type simple text in verbatim (that is, no extra colours, no fancy text formatting, etc.), simply use `\begin{SaveVerbatim}{mc}` ... `\end{SaveVerbatim}`, followed by `\printmacro` or `\printmacroi` on the next line. (Just like I did on the first example.)
- If you want to customise text in verbatim, then you need to pass special options to the `SaveVerbatim` environment, just like I did on my second and third examples. Options are passed inside the square brackets. You'll need to consult the [package documentation of `fancyvrb`](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) for more information on what you can do.
- At the moment, all `\printmacro` and `\printmacroi` boxes have the same frame style. And you need to call `\newmacroicon` whenever you wish to change the icon. If you prefer to have a separate command for each type of message, you need new declarations. For example, the following command can be used only for error messages, without the need to ever call `\newmacroicon`:

(this time the entire box is placed inside the `center` environment)

```
% \printmacroe prints text in verbatim with an error icon
\newcommand{\printmacroe}[1][mc]{%
%
{\setlength{\fboxrule}{3.0\fboxrule}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5\fboxsep}%
%
\begin{center}%
\fcolorbox{Red}{LightYellow}{%
%
\hspace{1em}%
\parbox[c]{0.75cm}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,width=0.75cm]{error-icon}}%
\hspace{1em}%
%
\settowidth{\macroiconwidth}{%
\hspace{1em}%
\parbox[c]{0.75cm}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,width=0.75cm]{error-icon}}%
\hspace{1em}}%
%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth - \macroiconwidth - 1.5cm}
\protect\UseVerbatim[fontsize=\footnotesize]{#1}
\end{minipage}}%
\end{center}
}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: A more elegant solution would exclude the need to call `\printmacro` or `\printmacroi` following the verbatim environment. However, the `SaverVerbatim` environment has the limitation that the line `\end{SaveVerbatim}` must occur *as is* in the document, not(!) inside a command or another environment. To understand the options passed to `SaveVerbatim`, consult the package documentation.

Comment: [Light bulb icon](http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconleak/or/256/light-bulb-icon.png) and [warning sign icon](http://images.wikia.com/ninjago/images/b/b2/Warning-icon.png).

Comment: That looks pretty complicated but works perfectly. But I try it on ... I don't understand how it works and almost can't understand even one command line above. But from my using it, It seems that the text was not really wrapped by the box. Since if you typing too long text, it won't wrap automatically. Well, this looks better, but give me pretty hard time to understand how to use :(

Comment: @user1285419 Text in verbatim is always printed *exactly* as it is typed. If you try using the standard `\begin{verbatim}` *text* `\end{verbatim}`, you always have to include line breaks manually. The `SaveVerbatim` used above works the same way. If you don't wish to make use of any special options, simply use `begin{SaveVerbatim}{macrolabel}` *text* `\end{SaveVerbatim}`. I will add some extra comments on my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will play around with your code. I think it gives me almost what I need. Just one question (don't be mad :) must I place \printmacroi every where after \end{SaveVerbatim}?  Is that possible to wrap all need command to one, so I can only call one command to show a tips-box, call another command to show a warning box ... etc.? Thanks.

Comment: @user1285419 I added some comments for your convenience. Hopefully they'll shed some light on what's happening. In my last example, `\printmacroe` should also be placed after `\end{SaveVerbatim}`. You can use it as a template to create other commands with different icons if you wish.

Answer (score 10):

Another, IMHO, elegant solution based on the great, but still relatively unknown [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package.

This package has the advantage, that it has built-in support for verbatim material (especially listings) and PGF/TikZ-based decorations, which provides a lot of graphical flexibility. It already comes with a stunning number of options, float support, etc.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,beramono}

\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
  icon/.style 2 args={%
   enlarge top by=4ex,
   skin=freelance, 
   frame code={%
     \tcb@drawframe@standard % standard implementation
     \node[at=(frame.north west),top color=#1, bottom color=#1!70!black, draw=#1!60!black, circle, font=\bfseries\huge]{#2};}
  },
  warning/.style={icon={red}{!}},
  question/.style={icon={green}{?}},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{%
    warning,
    listing only, 
    title=This is source code in XML, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    listing options={language=XML,columns=fullflexible,keywordstyle=\color{red}}
  } 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <project name="Package tcolorbox" default="documentation" basedir=".">
  <description> 
    Apache Ant build file (http://ant.apache.org/)
  </description> 
</project> 
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{%
    question,
    listing only, 
    title=This is source code in XML, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    listing options={language=XML,columns=fullflexible,keywordstyle=\color{red}}
  } 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <project name="Package tcolorbox" default="documentation" basedir=".">
  <description> 
    Apache Ant build file (http://ant.apache.org/)
  </description> 
</project> 
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You could try and use a combination of existing packages, lets say TikZ and minted:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1mm]
\node (code) {\inputminted[bgcolor=bg,frame=single,framerule=1pt]{python}{mplTest.py}};
\node [left=of code] {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{light-bulb-icon.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which yields (with appropriate code & icon files):
[image: example]

You could then wrap these into `newcommands` for each type, i.e. warning, error, etc.

**NOTE:** `minted` needs the Python language interpreter and the Pygments library installed.

Comment: @Sigur Yes it does.

Comment: Is `Pygments` necessary only for Python codes or for every example? My minimal example from page 4 of `minted` documentation is not working.

Comment: `Pygments` is needed regardless of which language the code you want to typeset is in.

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be [`bclogo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bclogo). It's main use it to build a framed and colored box with logo and title. Next you will find an example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,beramono}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{green},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    language=XML,%
    columns=fullflexible,%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur=green!30, logo=\bclampe]{}
\begin{lstlisting}
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <project name="Package tcolorbox" default="documentation" basedir=".">
  <description> 
    Apache Ant build file (http://ant.apache.org/)
  </description> 
</project> 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{bclogo}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur=red!30, logo=\bcdanger]{}
\begin{lstlisting}
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <project name="Package tcolorbox" default="documentation" basedir=".">
  <description> 
    Apache Ant build file (http://ant.apache.org/)
  </description> 
</project> 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Comment: This one looks pretty nice :)

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of this cute package!

Answer (score 5):

One way to do, what you want, is to `escape` from the listing using an `escapechar=` that is not used in the Code you're working with (I used `|` though thats not optimal for Java) and put an tikzpicture at the beginning of your code (you could extract that to commands line `\warningicon` or `\infoicon` and just put that command in the escaped part.

This would as an MWE look like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}frame=single,frameround=tttt,% rounded frame
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,tabsize=3,% code style
    backgroundcolor=\color{blue!25},%some background color
    language=Java,escapechar=|] %language and your escape char
|\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay] 
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (-1cm,0) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{lightbulb.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}|
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        System.out.println("Hello world !"); 
    } 
} 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here in the escaped part we place an `tikzpicture` as overlay including a node that is 1cm left of the `listing` where we include the lightbulb. Afterwards we define the usual code we want.

Together with

```
\newcommand{\lightbulbicon}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay] 
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (-1cm,0) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{lightbulb.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

The first line of an info-icon-code is just `|\lightbulbicon|`.

The complete result is something like
[image: Code with lightbulb]

Where of course you also can specify other positions of the lightbulb/icon depending on the `node anchor=` and the position of the node relative to the `listings` environment.

*Edit:* I just noticed that there is an linebreak too much after the ending `|` of the TikZ-Picture, hence your first line of code should be (in total)

```
|\lightbulbicon|public class Main {
```

which removes the first empty line in the picture.

Comment: It looks pretty neat. But just wonder if there is any way to move the icon inside the box and without overlap with the text

Comment: Well, now, the `overlay` kind of removes the picture from the usual text flow. If you include it into the flow, it is inside, moving the first line of code down (so there is no flow) and “breaking” the `backgroundcolor`.

Comment: The code doesn't fully work on my side. I can see the box but no icon shown if I put the |\lightbulbicon| inside the box, if I move it outside, it shows the icon there.

Comment: If you change the coordinates of the icon, i.e. to put the icon inside the box, the icon might be hidden behind the background color of the `listing` environment.