# How to make a fancy exam at LaTeX?

Tags: packages, exam, fancybox, esami

I'm very interested make a fancy exam at LaTeX? , You can see this example like this :

[image: fancy equation]

But, i don't know How to start it ? Can you explain **How to make it ?** or **What is the package at LaTeX** ?

Comment: The [exam](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam/) package is used for making exams. The header and graphics are probably put in using other packages.

Comment: Or the (arguably more powerful) [`exsheets`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/exsheets/exsheets_en.pdf) package.

Comment: Just remember, packages are supposed to make things easier, not harder.  Eventually you will want to do something the package can't handle.  The only thing difficult about the above are the graphics and $\displaystyle \frac...$

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is my post [here](http://matematikasiswa.blogspot.com/2014/01/pembimbingan-belajar-akhir-soal-soal.html). As mentioned by Fran, I use [bclogo](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/bclogo), by adding [the environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/how-to-make-a-textbox-with-this-tikz-code/22408#22408) of this forum. I wrote in the article document class. 
Most of the codes in the preamble is as follows:

```
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{28pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{16pt}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{{\color{biru} MATEMATIKA} \\ My school name}
\fancyhead[R]{\color{biru} Myname}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{mycolor}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}

\cfoot{}
\usepackage{lastpage} % for page numbering style
  %%"Page # of ##" -- Comment out to get default page numbering
  \cfoot{Halaman \thepage\ dari \pageref{LastPage}} % text in center footer
```

Answer (score 5):

A start for the "fancy" part with package `bclogo`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{enumitem,amstext,textcomp} 
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\logowidth{32pt}
\renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{\tikz%
\node[fill=blue!20, starburst, drop shadow, draw=black]{\color{blue}\bfseries\huge#1};\hfill}
\begin{bclogo}[
couleur = blue!05,
marge=20,
arrondi = 0.3, 
epBarre=3.5,
cadreTitre = false,
logo = \bccrayon, 
couleurBarre = red!80!blue!60,
ombre=true,
couleurOmbre = blue!20!black!30,
]
{Packet 1}
\bigskip
\huge
\begin{enumerate}
\item Tururan pertama bla bla bla ...
\begin{enumerate}[label={\Alph*.}~]
\item $f\text{\textasciiacute}(x)=\frac{-10}{(4x+3)^{2}}$
\item $f\text{\textasciiacute}(x)=\frac{-5}{(4x+3)^{2}}$
\item $f\text{\textasciiacute}(x)=\frac{-2}{(4x+3)^{2}}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{bclogo}
\end{document}
```

For the "exam" part, there are several packages for this at [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/topic/exam), but for multiple choice exams my suggestion will be out of there, but still free and still with LaTeX. Briefly, with [Auto Multiple Choice (AMC)](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/) you can make a LaTeX file (fancy or not) with questions and answers that can be randomized (both). This is not a great advantage over some others packages. The main difference is that the purpose is not to print one "new" exam that look different of the last year, with the same questions mixed in different order, o easily select question from a database, but print one numerated exam for each student, all with the same questions, but all in different order. For example, if you have a exam of 40 questions of 5 pages for 100 students, the AMC style can make automatically in seconds a PDF of 500 pages with 100 exams, and almost certainly you cannot find the same answer `15.c` within the one hundred exams.

A nightmare to correct it manually, I agree, but AMC is not only a `.sty` file for print a PDF but also a whole program (there are Windows, Linux and Mac versions)that can check scanned images of the exams and make a spreadsheet with the scores for each student, according to the created LaTeX template. Also can show the correct answers for the template or even for each generated exam  and make statistic about percentage of correct answers obtained for each question, so you can detect easily too easy/too hard/badly formulated questions.

Comment: ,, sorry, your code is not running, i get error ...starburst is not running, bclogo package error after updated database package latex yesterdaty , before i can running .....

Comment: i also try bclogo package in example my document , still get error at starburst part.

Comment: @HirWanto Sorry,  I have forgotten to include `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}` in the preamble. I will change ASAP.

Comment: OK, AFAIK, I still get error with bclogo package especially starburst part,

Comment: I wait your answers

Comment: Your Answers is not really same like i wanna it

Comment: Sorry, but I have no time to try to reproduce exactly your image. Instead `bclogo`, the frame can be made also with package `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`. There are many examples in this site for fine tuning of these packages. They all work with TikZ, so I guess the problem is only create a tikz node with the odd shape of your label and place it in  left top corner, as [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94865/11604).

Answer (score 1):

For the exam part, you can also have a look at the `esami` package, which can help you write the exam text and solution.
I don't know if you can substitute the numbers of the questions with your image, but you can try with the other packages that have been suggested in the previous answers.