# Create a special small box or environment for highlighting special content such examples, reference and links?

Tags: environments, boxes

I am trying to create a box or a coloured section with a border and a logo, something like this warning section:
[image]

Or like this, not so nice, code link:
[image]

Which is repeated during the book for highlighting when some reference to a code is used.

## What's the name of this typographical element?

## How can create my own?

I was trying to use `\newcommand` or `\newenvironment` but I would appreciate some recommendations before starting some trials.

Comment: Have you considered the [tcolorbox package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)?

Comment: @Cragfelt yes also the bclogo  but I can not understand how to add my own logo, I can use only the defult logos/icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Cragfelt` suggested, `tcolorbox` could be an alternative as it's shown in following example. [`bclogo`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94881/1952) could be another option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newtcolorbox{myalert}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    notitle,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=1pt,
    borderline west={2mm}{0mm}{red},
    width=.8\linewidth,
    center,
    before upper={\textcolor{red}{\large\faBomb\ }},
    #1
    }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{myalert}
This is some important advertisement!
\end{myalert}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: using own logos.**

Your own logo can be inserted with `\includegraphics` command. In following code you'll find three possible implementations with tcolorbox. The first one includes the logo as a `character`, the second one divides the box between logo and text and the third one uses `wrapfig` box to include a wrapped logo.

Used logo comes from [openclipart](https://openclipart.org/detail/25080/architetto-attenzione)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newtcolorbox{firstalert}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    notitle,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=1pt,
    borderline west={2mm}{0mm}{red},
    width=.8\linewidth,
    center,
    before upper={\includegraphics[height=8mm]{Atencio}\ },
    #1
    }

\newtcolorbox{secondalert}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    sidebyside,
    lefthand width=2cm,
    bicolor,
    colback=red!20,
    colbacklower=yellow!10,
    notitle,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=1pt,
    borderline west={2mm}{0mm}{red},
    width=.8\linewidth,
    center,
    #1
    }

\newtcolorbox{thirdalert}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    notitle,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=1pt,
    borderline west={2mm}{0mm}{red},
    width=.8\linewidth,
    center,
    before upper={\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.2\linewidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{Atencio}\end{wrapfigure}},
    #1
    }


\begin{document}
\begin{firstalert}
This is some important advertisement! \lipsum[2]
\end{firstalert}
%\lipsum[2]
\begin{secondalert}[width=.9\linewidth]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Atencio}
\tcblower
This is some important advertisement! \lipsum[2]
\end{secondalert}
\begin{thirdalert}[width=.9\linewidth]
This is some important advertisement! \lipsum[2]
\end{thirdalert}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 But how can I use my own logo instead of \faBomb?

Comment: @GM I've updated the answer with external logos.